# Почему this не может обращаться к функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, this

Я так понимаю, что `this` позволяет обращаться к тому объекту, в котором выполняется функция.

Если функция также является объектом, то почему же нельзя обратиться к "родительской" функции изнутри вложенной функции? Например так:

```js
function outerFunc() {
    return function innerFunc() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
outerFunc()();
```

Но так не выходит. Тут получается также само как и со стрелочными функциями. Внутренняя функция просто передает значение внешней. Она как будто не имеет своего собственного значения `this`

Почему так происходит? `this` может обращаться не ко всем объектам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` равно объекту, к которому функция принадлежит как его свойство, как его метод (и при этом будет вызвана как его метод). Если вы просто объявите функцию внутри функции, это не сделает внутреннюю функцию свойством внешней функции.

Если я правильно понимаю, ваши ожидания скорее отвечают такому коду:

```js
function outerFunc() {}

outerFunc.innerFunc = function () {
  console.log(this);
}

outerFunc.innerFunc(); // Выведет "function outerFunc() {}"
```

Comment: То есть такая запись через точку - `outerFunc.innerFunc = function () {}` позволяет добавлять в объект свойство. А если просто взять и записать функцию в функции - `function outer() { function inner() {} }`, то вложенная функция, как я понимаю, уже не будет считаться свойством "родительской" функции?

Comment: @Heaven Да, правильно.